# Error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.props.repos.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm new in React but I'm building a simple app to search GitHub users just put their usernames. It must bring me information about the users and theirs respective repositories, but I have a problem whit the code:

Errors:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.props.repos.map is not a function
>
> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null

Code:

```
var React = require('react');
var UserRepos = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {

        return {
            reposCount: 0,
        }
    },
    componentWillReceiveProps: function (props) {
        console.log(props);
        this.setState({reposCount: props.repos.length});
    },

    render: function () {
       var repos = this.props.repos.map(function (repo, key) {
            return (
                <div key={key} className="thumbnail">
                    <div className="caption">
                        <h3>{repo.name}
                            <span className="badge">{repo.stargazers_count} STARS</span>
                        </h3>
                        <p>{repo.description}</p>
                        <p>
                            <a href={repo.html_url} className="btn btn-primary" role="button">Repository</a>
                            <a href={repo.html_url + '/issues'} className="btn btn-default" role="button">Issues ({repo.open_issues}) </a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        });
               return (
                   <div>
                       <h2>{this.state.reposCount} repositories</h2>
                       {repos}
                   </div>
               )
    }
});

module.exports =UserRepos;
```

Comment: It means that whatever you're using to initialize `props.repos` isn't an array.

Comment: what value do you get for this.prop.repos in render function

Comment: Your render is being called before your props.repos is set up. In the render, account for this by checking if props.repos exists; if it doesn't then set it to an empty array. When the props.repos does get created, the render will be called again and then will work ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved!

Hi guys thanks for your help!

This was a beginner error!!!

In js file called UserInfo.js where I have a props was:

```
<UserRepos repos="{props.repos}" />
```

I just corrected it for

```
<UserRepos repos={props.repos} />
```

without quotes!

Thanks a million!!!

Answer (score -1):

You can fix error by doing this:

```
render: function () {
var reposArray=this.props.repos || [];
       var repos = reposArray.map(function (repo, key) {
...
...
....
```

What this will do is that if `this.props.repos` is not array (probably `undefined`) it will initialize `reposArray` variable to empty array.

Comment: Indeed using of default props is much better to gain the same result.

Answer (score -1):

This error means that `this.props.repos` is not an array.
So first of all ensure that repos passed to component is an array:

`<UserRepos repos={[repo1, repo2, ...]} />`

Also I'd like to recomend you to declare your component's propTypes:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    repos: PropTypes.array,
  },

  getDefaultProps() {
    return {
      repos: [],
    };
  },

  ...
});
```

Note: you need to install `prop-types` for this: `npm install --save prop-types`

Answer (score -1):

I would agree with the others on your issue most probably being one of the following:

- You haven't passed the *repos* prop properly. Check the parent method
  for this one.
- *repos* is not always an array. See how you are initialising it before you assign data to this variable. You can set it initially as
  `let repos = [];` to have it as an empty array before it gets any
  data.

Also, if you are new to React, definitively go with *PropTypes*, they are a life saver, and will help you catch these kinds of issues on component mounting.

This is my take on your issue (ES6): https://jsfiddle.net/Lx9gfj5f/3/